# Why does logging an array to console before and after an operation on it show the same output in each case

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, I start with:

```
        var currentHistory = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5'];
        console.log(currentHistory);
```

I then swap an element and log again:

```
        var tmp = currentHistory[2];
        currentHistory[2] = currentHistory[0];
        currentHistory[0] = tmp;

        console.log(currentHistory);
```

Only to see that the output is the same in each case.

```
        Array[5] 't3', 't2', 't1', 't4', 't5'

        Array[5] 't3', 't2', 't1', 't4', 't5'
```

This inconsistency in space and time sent me quite mad last night and an answer would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: I get ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"] then ["t3", "t2", "t1", "t4", "t5"]  in chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! Try this:

```
console.log(currentHistory.slice(0));
```

Notice now the big ball of wibbly-wobbly, timey-wimey stuff has resolved into a simple line from A to B?

This is actually an issue with how the console works. When you log an object, some browsers (particularly Chrome) log a reference to the object so you can browse it freely. However, if the object changes... it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @GôTô Depends on if your console is open before or after the code is run ;)

Comment: I see, that example maintains the expected state of the array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/GDUB7/) your code works fine.

im using chrome Version 34.0.1847.131 m

Comment: Different consoles I believe

Comment: i dont think it makes any difference. javascript is javascript, and despite the different support of the browsers, this array operation is a basic operation. please make sure you didnt reload the array accidentally. it should and will work, and the only thing that comes to mind is accidental re-definition of the array before the 2nd print.

Comment: It does. That's why we're seeing different results. See the answer above and similar question